Monodromy for nonclosed paths
I've came across this proof of a theorem called "monodromy theorem" (in a completely non-analytical context) for closed paths that is as follows:
Let $(Y,p)$ be a covering of $X$ and let $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ be two homotopic loops on $X$ with base point $x_0$. Than, given $\tilde{x}\in p^{-1}(x_0)$ and given $\tilde{\sigma}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}'$ the liftings such that $\tilde{\sigma}(0)=\tilde{\sigma}'(0)=\tilde{x}$, you have that $\tilde{\sigma}(1)=\tilde{\sigma}'(1)$.
Proof. Let $H$ be the homotopy between the loops in $X$. Thanks to the homotopy lifting property there is only one homotopy $\tilde{H}$ between $\tilde{\sigma}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}'$. Additionally you have that $\tilde{H}(1,s)\in p^{-1}(x_0)$ for all $s\in[0,1]$. Now, since $x_0$ admits an evenly covered open that contains it, every point on the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$ is contained by a disjoint open, and since $[a,b]$ is connected and $\tilde{H}(1,s)$ is continuous, the image of $\tilde{H}(1,s)$ is connected, and so it's constant.
My issue with this proof is the following: when did we used that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are closed? Cause I've rewritten the proof replacing all $x_0$ with $x_1$ (the ending point of a nonclosed path) and I can't find how it fails:
Let $(Y,p)$ be a covering of $X$ and let $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ be two homotopic paths on $X$ with starting point $x_0$ and ending point $x_1$. Than, given $\tilde{x}\in p^{-1}(x_0)$ and given $\tilde{\sigma}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}'$ the liftings such that $\tilde{\sigma}(0)=\tilde{\sigma}'(0)=\tilde{x}$, you have that $\tilde{\sigma}(1)=\tilde{\sigma}'(1)$.
Proof. Let $H$ be the homotopy between the paths in $X$. Thanks to the homotopy lifting property there is only one homotopy $\tilde{H}$ between $\tilde{\sigma}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}'$. Additionally you have that $\tilde{H}(1,s)\in p^{-1}(x_1)$ for all $s\in[0,1]$. Now, since $x_1$ admits an evenly covered open that contains it, every point on the fiber $p^{-1}(x_1)$ is contained by a disjoint open, and since $[a,b]$ is connected and $\tilde{H}(1,s)$ is continuous, the image of $\tilde{H}(1,s)$ is connected, and so it's constant.
Now, am I missing something or the proof holds? Did the author just care not about nonclosed paths?

The proof holds, and the original proof (and yours too, as a consequence) don't exactly exude diligence to begin with, so to speak: For one, the claim that there is a unique homotopy $\tilde{H}$ between $\tilde{\sigma}$ and and $\tilde{\sigma}'$ is flat out wrong without the additional qualifier "lifting $H$," and both $H$'s appearing in the last sentence should be $\tilde{H}$'s. For a better reference, see A. Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, paragraph following Prop. 1.30 and following. It's essentially the same argument, in words, applied to general paths.

Yes sorry, the proofs I've written here are just a hasty transcription of the one I've read, so it's not very thorough.
